# Nested JSON array not updating in DB

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, sqlite, sqlalchemy

Using: Python 3.7.3, SQLAlchemy 1.3.13 with sqlite.

I'm struggling to append data within the following JSON structure into a JSON field in my database.

This is the sort of thing that I'm seeking to achieve but what I'm struggling to do is add: "Second message", "Third message", etc...

```
data = {
    "title":'some title',
    "status": "some status",
    "logs": [
        [mytimestamp, "First message"],
        [mytimestamp, "Second message"],
        [mytimestamp, "Third message"]
    ]
}
```

Inserting the above data structure into the database works fine. Like this:

```
tablename = Tablename(someint=1, data=data)
try:
    db.session.add(tablename)
    db.session.commit()  <--- success every time
except:
    print('Error creating record')
```

Updating and amending top level items (such as "title", "status") I can do without problem. I can even add extra ones.

```
tablename = Tablename.query.get(id)
try:
    tablename.data = newdata <--- newdata is where the problem is
    tablename.someint = 2 <--- this always updates without problem
    db.session.commit()
except:
    print('Error updating record')
```

But when it comes to adding extra array items into "logs" this is where it goes completely weird... the database record WILL update but with the exception of my JSON field but it equally does not throw an exception, it just updates other database columns but ignores my JSON field.

I've tried various ways of append(), update(), even this works `tablename.data = {**olddata, **newdata}` but ONLY for top level items. As soon as I try to manipulate the data WITHIN "logs" then it:

- Either: errors because I'm trying to manipulate the data incorrectly (fair enough)
- Or: silently ignores the fact that I am updating the data column EVEN if when I print(newdata) and the output value that I want to put into the db and I CAN SEE that it is correct ... but the db just ignores it!

What I don't get is that `data` will happily get inserted into the DB in the first place, and I can then find ways to update the object (even if it's ugly, at this stage I just want it to work!) that I get out of the database via a query but what I don't understand is why I can print the resulting object to CLI and it looks ok but the DB just silently ignores it (`someint` always gets updated during silent fails)! At least throw an error if it's not valid?

Anyone have any ideas? How would you append lines to "logs"?

### --- IMPORTANT UPDATE ---

As the results I was getting yesterday made no logical sense to me at all, I dropped the subject and have come back today with fresh eyes. This is what I've done and found so far, my findings are **not pleasing** but at least I have a solution that now appears to be working: use a VARCHAR field instead of a JSON field in the database.

This is how I reached my conclusion:

I added an extra column to my database table, so now I have:

```
data1 -> type: JSON
data2 -> type: VARCHAR
```

This is my test code:

```
# Get the data
tablename = Tablename.query.get(id)
d1 = tablename.data1 # from JSON field
d2 = json.loads(tablename.data2) # from VARCHAR field

# Append a log message
logs = d1['logs'] # <--- See note 1 below
# logs = d2['logs'] # <--- See note 2 below
logs.append([mytimestamp, message])
newlogs = {'logs': logs}

# Update database record with new data
tablename.data1 = {**d1, **newlogs} # Into JSON field
tablename.data2 = json.dumps({**d2, **newlogs}) # Into VARCHAR field
db.session.commit()
```

Note 1: If I use `d1` as the source (i.e: from JSON column) then the `data1` field doesn't get updated with new message but `data2` field does!

Note 2: If I use `d2` as the source (i.e: from VARCHAR column) then both `data1` and `data2` fields are successfully updated with the new message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A work around/solution has been found!

The problem is in fact, according to the documentation, expected behaviour. The [SQLAlchemy documentation](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/type_basics.html#sqlalchemy.types.JSON) states, and I quote:

***Detecting Changes in JSON columns when using the ORM***:
The JSON type, when used with the SQLAlchemy ORM, does not detect in-place mutations to the structure. In order to detect these, the sqlalchemy.ext.mutable extension must be used. This extension will allow “in-place” changes to the datastructure to produce events which will be detected by the unit of work. See the example at HSTORE for a simple example involving a dictionary.

The downside is that implementing the above is relatively complicated and more importantly "expensive". However, a much easier and simpler solution, that I have found, is to always update a top-level item whenever you want to make a change. For example, updating the value of `last_updated` in the example below every time you want to add a new item into the `logs` array will cause the full record to be updated. Failing to do so will mean that your updated JSON data will be lost and even a `try: except:` won't tell you about it.

```
data = {
    "title":'some title',
    "status": "some status",
    "last_updated": int(floor(time.time() * 1000)),
    "logs": [
        [mytimestamp, "First message"],
        [mytimestamp, "Second message"],
        [mytimestamp, "Third message"]
    ]
}
```

Comment: Is there any other solution to this, other than maintaining a timestamp?

Comment: It doesn't have to be the timestamp, it can be any of the top level items.

Comment: I found a couple of solutions at https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/discussions/6473